# Tortoise SVN diff two trees

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Consider the following situation

1. Code was added to the trunk at revision x
2. A branch was created
3. The modifications of rev x were removed from trunk in rev x+10 and new code was added
4. trunk and branch goes their own ways till rev x+100
5. Now we need to update the branch with changes form the trunk

The problem with a simple "merge a range of revisions" is that due to step 3, the initial branch modifications are being removed. Is there any way to work around this without resorting to manual merge.

Version Info: `TortoiseSVN 1.6.7, Build 18415 - 32 Bit , 2010/01/22 17:55:06 Subversion 1.6.9,`

Comment: And No. I cannot switch to Hg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes from revision x were removed and new changes were made all in one commit, then there is no way to sort this out other than manually. The smallest union of changes SVN can handle is one commit.

However, you don't have to sort out the mess of x+10 and all the rest of the changes in one go. What you could do is a temporary branch `temp` of the trunk at x+9, merge x+10 into that manually sorting out the removal of x from the rest of the changes done at x+10. Then you first merge branch `temp` into your branch and then all the changes from (x+11) to (x+100) from the trunk, sorting out whatever problems come from that.

Comment: rev x+10 isnt pure removal. there was new code added in it too. I will update the wuestion to reflect this